# How to Change .NET Version Target

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I am creating a service which was originally targeting `.NET 4.5`.

I changed this to `.NET 3.5` in the Project Properties:

[image]

I also updated all of the `.resx` files to contain `Version=2.0.0.0` instead of `Version=4.0.0.0` (as the compiler was complaining about this), and I also removed `.NET 4.5` from the list of prerequisites.

However, when I generate a new MSI and try to run I am seeing this message:

> This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.5. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again. The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web. Would you like to do this now?

The machine I am trying to install this on has `.NET 3.5` installed and so this should run without issue.

I am not sure what else to check in my project - does anyone have any ideas of what might be causing this? Is there some way of "refreshing" the settings to ensure that the new framework is used by the installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by going into the Setup Project's `Detected Dependancies`:

[image]

For some reason this was set to `.NET 4.5`.

Changing this to the required version fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change Target Framework in Project Properties and Recompile. That's all...

Comment: As you can see from the question I already did that and it did not work